# Drools-Equivalent of the "not in" SQL

Tags: java, drools

I have two tables A and B. I want to update column A in table A if it doesn't have a match with column B in table B.

I've written the following, but it doesn't work.

```
rule "Lookup"

when
  B($colB: colB)
  $a : A($colB not contains colA)

then 
  modify($a){
   setcolA(1000)
 }
end
```

I've tried using accumulate as well but in vain. Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Equivalent in SQL is

```
Update colA set colA =1000 from A where colA not in (Select colB from B)
```

Comment: What does it have to do with Java?

Comment: @Amongalen Drools is written in Java and can execute Java code.

Comment: Firstly, It is required to have a List of values of colB of table B. You can group them by using collectList().  Then you can use not contains to check where the list has the value or not. A brief detail is here. http://blog.athico.com/2007/06/chained-from-accumulate-collect.html

Comment: This can't be answered without knowing the datatypes of colA and colB. If the class definitions of `A` and `B` were added, this would be an answerable question.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in a comment, this depends on what data types colA and colB.

But let's say we have something like this:

```
class Person {
  String name;
}

class Cohort {
  List<String> names;
}
```

And what you want to do is add the person's name to the list of names in the cohort if the name isn't already present. (This is obviously a contrived example since the Real World solution would be to use a `Set`, not a `List`, but this is for illustrative purposes only.)

Now we can write a rule that tests if the name is not present like this:

```
rule "Add person to cohort"
when
  Person( $name: name )
  $cohort: Cohort( names not contains $name )
then
  // make the modification here
end
```

Note that in addition to `contains`/`not contains`, there's also a `memberOf`/`not memberOf` pair of operators. Which one you use depends on whether you're testing that a field is part of a collection, or a collection contains a field.

For completeness's sake, you might use `memberOf` like this:

```
rule "At least one person is not in the cohort"
when
  Cohort( $names: names )
  exists( Person( name not memberOf $names ) )
then
  // there exists at least one Person whose name is not in the cohort's name list
end
```

Further, if your list is hard-coded, we even have `in`/`not in` operators.

```
rule "Shirt color not valid"
when
  Shirt( color not in ("red", "blue", "green"))
then
  // the shirt color is some other color, eg "yellow"
end

rule "Unable to ship to country"
when
  Order( country in ("Canada", "Puerto Rico") )
then
  //
end
```

---

Of course, the `contains` version a lot like your example which "doesn't work", which makes me think that your data types are not an object plus a collection. Maybe you're trying to find an *intersection* of two collections -- that's a different sort of algorithm which you could implement using `accumulate` and `collect`.

But for the question as-is, these three sets of operators (`contains`/`not contains` ; `memberOf`/`not memberOf` ; and `in`/`not in`) are the three ways you can figure out if an item is present in a collection.